# Como converter string minúscula para maiúscula em Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

Fiz este código que lê uma frase e determina se a primeira letra é maiúscula ou não, agora tenho que varrer toda a frase alterando onde for minúsculo para maiúsculo, mas estou com problema de como fazer isso.

```
segment .data
msn db "Entre com uma frase:",sl
tam equ $-msn

msn1 db "Sua frase  comeca com  letra maiuscula:", sl
tam1 equ $-msn1

msn2 db "Sua frase nao comeca com  letra maiuscula:",sl
tam2 equ $-msn2

msn3 db " ",sl
tam3 equ $-msn3

sl equ 10
segment .bss
buf resb 100
buf2 resb 2


segment .text
global main
main:

     ;exibe string
      mov edx,tam    ;tamanho
      mov ecx,msn   ;ponteiro
      call print_str

 
     ;ler strim
      mov edx,100     ;tamanho da string
      mov ecx,buf    ;destino
      mov ebx, 0     ;Teclado
      mov eax, 3     ;read 
      int 0x80
      
      mov al,[buf +0]
      mov [buf2],al
      
      cmp byte[buf2,0],65
      jl minusculo 
      cmp byte[buf2,0],90
      jg minusculo 
      
      mov edx,tam1
      mov ecx, msn1  
      call print_str
 
      jmp fim
    
      
minusculo:
    
      mov edx,tam2
      mov ecx, msn2    
      call print_str

fim:      
      mov edx,tam3
      mov ecx,msn3
      call print_str

       
; ----------------- AREA DOS PROCEDIMENTOS ------------------

print_str:
    mov ebx, 1          ; Descritor (monitor = 1)
    mov eax, 4          ; Servico (print)
    int 0x80            ; Executa (exibe)
    ret             ; Devolve ao chamador
```

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre maiúscula e minúscula na tabela ASCII (para letras não acentuadas) é apenas o 6º bit.

Para transformar de minúscula para maiúscula, basta resetar o bit 6 ou fazer um AND lógico com DFH = 1101 1111 ou ainda subtrair 20H.

```
61H = 0110 0001 -> a

41H = 0100 0001 -> A

...

7AH = 0111 1010 -> z

5AH = 0101 1010 -> Z
```

Para transformar de maiúscula para minúscula, basta setar o bit 6 ou fazer um OR lógico com 20H = 0010 0000 ou ainda somar 20H.

```
41H = 0100 0001 - A

61H = 0110 0001 - a

...

5AH = 0101 1010 -> Z

7AH = 0111 1010 -> z
```

Isso é válido apenas nos intervalos de 41H a 5AH e 61H a 7AH.

Note, também, que se utilizar AND na letra maiúscula, ela permanecerá maiúscula, o mesmo ocorrendo com o OR: a letra minúscula permanecerá minúscula.

Para o programa em questão, leia cada bit da string, compare com o intervalo, efetue um AND lógico com DFh e imprima ou salve o caractere.

Answer (score 1):

Vi que a pergunta é relativamente antiga mas publiquei a resposta agora para que sirva para outros Devs.
Para mudar texto tudo para Maiúscula esse código funciona bem.

.data

```
texto: .space 256
```

.text

main:

```
li $v0, 8
li $a1, 256
la $a0, texto
syscall

li $v0, 4
li $t0, 0
```

loop:

```
lb $t1, texto($t0)
beq $t1, 0, exit
blt $t1, 'a', not_lower
bgt $t1, 'z', not_lower
sub $t1, $t1, 32
sb $t1, texto($t0)
not_lower:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
j loop
```

exit:

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, texto
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```